# JAXB Java Runtime Error with Getter but no Setter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using the following class:

```
package com.mycom.ecnviewerview.viewer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Report {

private String srunDate = null;
private String sUserID = null;
private List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();

@XmlElement
public String getRunDate()
{
    return this.srunDate;
}

public void setRunDate(String pRunDate)
{
    this.srunDate = pRunDate;
}

@XmlElement
public String getUser()
{
    return this.sUserID;
}

public void SetUser(String pUser)
{
    this.sUserID = pUser;
}

@XmlElement
public List<Result> getResults()
{
    return results;
}

public void SetResults(List<Result> pResults)
{
    results = pResults;
}
```

}

And when I call the following code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Report.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event ) {
throw new RuntimeException(event.getMessage(),
event.getLinkedException());
}
});     

Report report = (Report) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader("C:\\Temp\\File.xml"));

txtRunBy.setText(report.getUser());
txtRunDate.setText(report.getRunDate());
results = report.getResults();
```

The error is:

Err=java.lang.RuntimeException: The property has a getter "public java.lang.String com.mycom.ecnviewerview.viewer.Report.getUser()" but no setter. For unmarshalling, please define setters. (Or if this is a collection property, make sure that the getter returns a collection instance.)

I'm confused because I believe that I have a getter and a setter.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the convention is methods start with a lower case name. Change your setters from

```
public void SetUser(String pUser)
{
    this.sUserID = pUser;
}
```

to

```
public void setUser(String pUser)
{
    this.sUserID = pUser;
}
```

and the others.

Comment: Elliott, thanks for the tip, I just figured it and was coming to post that answer!